# CakePHP Migration Creating a new table causes duplicate column name

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, migration, phinx

I created a new Migration script on CakePHP 3 using the following command

```
bin/cake bake migration CreateOfficialTeams id:int name:string topic_id:int
```

The `id` field should be the primary key, and `topic_id` is a foreign key. The script comes out like I want, except `topic_id` is a string for some reason, but I manually fix that.

When I attempt to run the script I get an error stating:

```
Exception: SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'id' in [/home/bradygp/workspace/vendor/robmorgan/phinx/src/Phinx/Db/Adapter/PdoAdapter.php, line 306]
2017-02-27 21:52:16 Error [PDOException] SQLSTATE[45S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'id'
```

I have other tables with a column name of 'id', but this is a new table, called with the `create()` function,

Comment: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/migrations.html#creating-custom-primary-keys

Comment: @ndm Ah, that was it. the migration script will automatically create the id and when I was trying to create one too, there was a duplicate column error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove ID. ID column is automatically created, so you don't need to write it.
bin/cake bake migration CreateOfficialTeams name:string topic_id:int

Answer (score 0):

The primary key column named id will be added implicitly. CakePHpp 3 
For more detail you can visit on 
[Cakephp Migration overview](http://Cakephhttps://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/migrations.html#overview)

Answer (score 0):

Unusual behavior.

In the cakeBook:
"The primary key column named id will be added implicitly."
but in bilder adds to the migration files:

```
bin/cake bake migration_spanshot Initial
```

Result file:

```
 $this->table('admin_menus')
            ->addColumn('id', 'integer', [
                'autoIncrement' => true,
                'default' => null,
                'limit' => 11,
                'null' => false,
            ])
            ->addPrimaryKey(['id'])
            ->addColumn('role_user_id', 'integer', [
                'default' => '0',
                'limit' => 11,
                'null' => true,
            ])
```